# Adding a String into a scanner

Tags: java, string

//I wanted to insert a decimal number to console (like 1.85) to the String groesse and I also wanted it to be in the equation of bmi. How do i do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

bmiRechner(out);

out.flush();
}

public static void bmiRechner(PrintWriter out) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    String = groesse;
    
    out.println("Schönen Guten Tag");
    out.flush();
    out.println("Geben Sie ihre Körpergröße in Metern an");
    out.flush();
    groesse = sc.next();
    out.println("Geben Sie nun ihr Körpergewicht in Kilogramm ein");
    out.flush();
    int gewicht = sc.nextInt();
    
    double bmi = gewicht / Math.pow(groesse, 2);
    
    out.println("Das ist Ihr BMI: " + bmi);
    
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I highly recommend you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This will help you to improve the quality of your questions. **For every question, please show the attempts you have tried and the error messages you get from your attempts.**

Comment: If you want to add or alter information coming in on System.in, you should create an intermediary (I'd suggest ByteArrayInput/OutputStreams). You can write to the byte array using input from System.in, then add what you want. And then use a ByteArrayOutputStream instead of reading directly from System.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i do that?

OK, so you want to read user input from the console. To do so, instead of ...

```
groesse = sc.next();
```

use

```
// This line will get the input line 
groesse = sc.nextLine().trim();

// This will get the numeric value of the input
double groesse = Double.valueOf(groesse)
```

The same applies to the other measurement.